# Does the microwave generating component in a microwave operate under the same physics as an antenna radio transmitter?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, antennas, microwaves

Essentially does the component of a microwave which generates those microwave photons operate using an AC power supply connected to a broken circuit which causes an oscillating dipole to radiate electromagnetic radiation? Is there any amplification that is needed?

Comment: the first microwave ovens were called radar ranges, as it was discovered that early radar systems transmitting microwaves could heat objects.

Answer (score 0):

it has an AC power supply connected to an unbroken (not sure what you mean by "broken") circuit called a *microwave oscillator*. At the frequencies generated by that circuit, the dipole antenna it feeds looks like a piece of hollow pipe with a flared-out end on it, pointing into the oven chamber.

The necessary amplification is generated by the vacuum tube (called a *magnetron*) in the circuit that also does the oscillating.

The basic physics is the same as that in a lower-frequency radio transmitter, but the implementation details are different because of how high the operating frequency of the microwave tube is.

Comment: maybe broken was the wrong word... Is open loop the right phrasing? 1:54 in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWVPJSoJDzA